# Laravel Eloquent relationships With does not work

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, relation

I am trying this code but in `whith` `where` **query** does not work
any One can solve this problem?

```
Quotation::with(['QuoParts', 'client'=>function($cq){
            $cq->orWhere('first_name', 'LIKE', '%Muhammad%');
        }, 'user'])->orWhere(function($q) use ($s){
            $q->orWhere('sku', 'LIKE', '%'.$s.'%');
            $q->orWhere('issue_date', 'LIKE', '%'.$s.'%');
            
        })->take($length)->skip($r->start)->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After lot of searching i have solved that by Using `WhereHas` closure `function`**

````
$q = Quotation::with(['QuoParts', 'user', 'client'])->whereHas('client', function ($query) use ($s) {
            $query->where('sku', 'like', '%' . $s . '%');
            $query->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%' . $s . '%');
            $query->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $s . '%');
        })->orWhereHas('user', function ($query) use ($s) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $s . '%');
            
        })
            ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($s) {
                $q->orWhere('sku', 'LIKE', '%' . $s . '%');
                $q->orWhere('issue_date', 'LIKE', '%' . $s . '%');
            })
            ->take($length)
            ->skip($r->start)
            ->get();```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
$posts = App\User::whereHas('posts', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', `foo%');
})->get();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `where()`, then after that `orWhere()`

```
Quotation::with([
    'QuoParts', 'user', 'client' => function ($cq) {
        $cq->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%Muhammad%');
    },
])->where(function ($q) use ($s) {
    $q->where('sku', 'LIKE', '%' . $s . '%');
    $q->orWhere('issue_date', 'LIKE', '%' . $s . '%');

})->take($length)->skip($r->start)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but its does not work